# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { while starting

Tags: node.js, npm, bots, discord, discord.js

> **Cause:**

So, i was messing around with nodejs version (update) and i accidently made my nodejs program not work anymore. Problem with this is i dont remember what nodejs version i had before this. Atleast, it started happening when i did this.

> **Problem:**

when i `node app.js` start my program, i get the following:

```
 $ node app.js
 /home/user/ftp/discordbot/schwi/app.js:3
 const {token} = require(path.join(__dirname, 'auth.json'));
       ^

 SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
     at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
     at startup (node.js:136:18)
     at node.js:966:3
```

Now i know that my code is correct considering it has been working before this.

PS: the `{ }` is needed in other classes considering i use alot of variables. It just happend to be that in this token case its only 1 variable.

> **Code:**

```
const path = require('path');
const Ononoki = require(path.join(__dirname, 'Ononoki.js'));
const {token} = require(path.join(__dirname, 'auth.json'));

start = function () {
    new Ononoki(token).init();
};

start();
```

To be honest i have no idea what the cause can be other than the version of node or something is wrong. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: update it to the latest version.

Comment: i tried that. but i get the following error.

`return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));`

`Error: libcairo.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
`

Comment: which version you are currently running? you can check that by `node -v` in terminal

Comment: @McRist my original error is V4.2.6. my comment here error is v10.8.0.

But for now i am working on my new droplet which is version 4.2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing node_modules and run npm install again in the root folder.

`$ rm -rf node_modules/`

`$ npm update`

`$ npm install`

Comment: Finished installation with errors. But its working flawlessly! `node app.js` starts my application. However, i am getting this and more errors: `node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.0.0/node-v64-linux-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@4.0.0 and node@10.8.0 (node-v64 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)` anything major i should be concerned about?

Comment: successfully removed node_modules ?

Comment: Yes it was a success. app is working fine now. but i got alot of errors while updating. i didnt even `npm install` after.